# How to create an android app that opens a website

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using eclipse. Just started with android web apps :) !

I want to create a web application that whenever it's open, it loads a website.

Nothing visual, no buttons.

This is the main blank code I have:

```
package com.example.yellowtest;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: let me tell you google doesn't allow apps which just redirects to a website ...

Answer (score 3):

Here the sample code for web application

activity_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/google"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private WebView webView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.google);
    startWebView("https://www.google.com/");
  }


  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
  private void startWebView(String url) {
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
      ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
        }

        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
          if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
          }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          try {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
              progressDialog.dismiss();
              progressDialog = null;
             }
           } catch(Exception exception) {
             exception.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

      }); 

      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
      webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
      webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
      webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
      webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
      webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      webView.loadUrl(url);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
      } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
      }
    }
}
```

use this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I added these and it has much less errors.. 

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

Comment: Create a new Android project.just paste the code. no need to import.when you select the Error it will shows the import option

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: :), put a webview in your xml layout named "activity_main" with id "@+id/webview"

Comment: Should I import "WebView" ?

Comment: Off course, import everything which is necessary for your project.

Comment: It's the first time doing this, how do I add the webview in my xml layout?

Comment: <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

/>      paste this in your activity_main.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65146/discussion-between-hatul-and-murtaza-hussain).

Comment: Maybe thats not the best solution because they use the ActionBarActivity which is only included in the support-lib. It's better for understanding to use the normal Activity...Use this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26994965/1231245

Answer (score 0):

Have alook at PhoneGap/Cordova, webaps with API
http://cordova.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code. It contains webview client which is safest one.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/*
 * Demo of creating an application to open any URL inside the application and clicking on any link from that URl 
should not open Native browser but  that URL should open in the same screen.
 */
public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```